# C if condition comparing result of unsigned long bitwise operation with 0 is evaluated as false although true expected ( 0 == 0 is false)

Tags: c, if-statement, bitwise-operators, endianness, unsigned-long-long-int

`versionNumberAndPlaceNumber` being `0xFFFF00` the true case of the following `if` is not entered:

```
if(versionNumberAndPlaceNumber & 0xFFUL == 0UL) {
```

Why would this be?

.

### Here follows a longer code excerpt:

```
if(bytes_received == 27) {      // the data size of "struct bee" (padded), version number (8 bits) and place number of struct place
printf("\n27\n");
                unsigned long versionNumberAndPlaceNumber = 0;
                memcpy(&versionNumberAndPlaceNumber, &(read[24]), 8);     // read 8 = sizeof(long) on x64 bytes, hope it's faster than transferring less bytes on x64 (into possibly a register)
                /* memcpy copies bytes from increasing source address to increasing destination address, x64 this is supposed to run on is Little Endian thus for example [0xFF, 0x00, ...] as an unsigned long is ...0000000011111111 = 255 */
printf("\n%lu\n", versionNumberAndPlaceNumber);
                if(versionNumberAndPlaceNumber & 0xFFUL == 0UL) {          // version 0 of data for version 0 of this server
printf("\nv correct\n");
                    unsigned long location[3];
```

**(Note the read buffer is 32 bytes.)**

And here's the output:

```
27

16776960
```

.

### Debugging:

Instead of printing `versionNumberAndPlaceNumber` I also printed the whole `if` condition (indicating `%d` instead of `%lu`) and got `0` as output thus the condition appears to be false.

But `16776960` = `0xFFFF00` and `0xFFFF00` `AND` `0xFF` is `0`.

Why is `0 == 0` `false` ?

Comment: The condition `(a & b == c)` is the same as `(a & (b == c))`.

Comment: right, when I looked up the C operator precedence I glanced too briefly and mixed the "&" address operator with the "&" bitwise operator. The address operator has higher precedence than the `==` but the bitwise oeprator hasn't.

Comment: If in doubt with a complex expression, use brackets, else use brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` operator has higher operator precedence, than `&` (bitwise AND) therefore your condition is equal to this

```
if(versionNumberAndPlaceNumber & (0xFFUL == 0UL)) // 0xFFFF00 & 0 -> 0 -> false
```

Answer (score 1):

[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/book/operator_precedence) describes the order in which operations will occur.  This is the same as PEMDAS in maths class and is to reduce the number of parentheses required.  The `==` operator has a precedence of 9, `&` a precedence of 10, so the `==` operator grabs its arguments first.

This means that `(a & b == c)` is the same as `(a & (b == c))`, which is not what you expected.